# HQL to check for NULL in OneToOne relation

Tags: hibernate, hql, one-to-one

Here are my two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "aog_reference")
public class AogReference
{
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="aogReference", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, optional=true)
    private Pack pack;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "pack")
public class Pack
{

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="aog_reference")   
    private AogReference aogReference;

}
```

I can read and write both these entities using Hibernate and the ***pack*** property of AogReference is correctly populated.

However, I'm trying to run a HQL query that includes AogReference entities that don't have a pack referencing them.

Having read a load of stuff on this, I would expect this to work:

```
SELECT e FROM AogReference AS e left join e.pack  WHERE  (e.pack IS NULL)
```

But I get 0 lines returned, even though I know there are AogReference entities that dont have any references from Pack entities.

I have looked at the SQL generated by the above hql and it looks like this:

```
   select
        aogreferen0_.id as id1_0_,
        aogreferen0_.active as active2_0_,
        aogreferen0_.created as created3_0_,
        aogreferen0_.modified as modified4_0_,
        aogreferen0_.version as version5_0_,
        aogreferen0_.aog_delivery_number as aog_deli6_0_,
        aogreferen0_.aog_destination as aog_dest7_0_,
        aogreferen0_.aog_notes as aog_note8_0_,
        aogreferen0_.foc_notification_time as foc_noti9_0_,
        aogreferen0_.is_collection_today as is_coll10_0_,
        aogreferen0_.is_used as is_used11_0_,
        aogreferen0_.work_stream as work_st12_0_ 
    from
        aog_reference aogreferen0_ 
    left outer join
        pack pack1_ 
            on aogreferen0_.id=pack1_.aog_reference 
    where
        aogreferen0_.id is null
```

or simplified:

```
 select * 
 from 
   aog_reference a 
 left outer join 
    pack p on a.id = p.aog_reference 
 where a.id is null
```

Now notice the monster bug:

```
where a.id is null
```

Hibernate has got this completely wrong.  The generated sql should be this:

```
 select
        aogreferen0_.id as id1_0_,
        aogreferen0_.active as active2_0_,
        aogreferen0_.created as created3_0_,
        aogreferen0_.modified as modified4_0_,
        aogreferen0_.version as version5_0_,
        aogreferen0_.aog_delivery_number as aog_deli6_0_,
        aogreferen0_.aog_destination as aog_dest7_0_,
        aogreferen0_.aog_notes as aog_note8_0_,
        aogreferen0_.foc_notification_time as foc_noti9_0_,
        aogreferen0_.is_collection_today as is_coll10_0_,
        aogreferen0_.is_used as is_used11_0_,
        aogreferen0_.work_stream as work_st12_0_ 
    from
        aog_reference aogreferen0_ 
    left outer join
        pack pack1_ 
            on aogreferen0_.id=pack1_.aog_reference 
    where
        pack1_.id is null
```

Notice the last line is now:

```
 where pack1_.id is null
```

The sql that Hibernate generated is checking for the id on AogReference when it should be checking on the id of Pack.

The corrected sql works when I fire it at my database.

This looks to me like a massive bug in Hibernate. It simply has not generated the right sql.

Any comments (sensible ones) gratefully received.

Thanks,

Ed.

UPDATE:  It seems this is a [hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4795) and it has been around since 2010.

Comment: Seems like you need to change the "owning side" from Pack to Aog by adding a foreign key column to Aog. It is possible to keep the foreign key on Pack also, just make sure to maintain it.

Comment: I shouldn't need to add a foreign key on AogReference into Pack.  The documentation says so.   Here's the link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association.   It explicitly states: "To declare a side as not responsible for the relationship, the attribute mappedBy is used. mappedBy refers to the property name of the association on the owner side. In our case, this is passport. As you can see, you don't have to (must not) declare the join column since it has already been declared on the owners side."

Answer (score 2):

As you already mentioned, this seems to be a known [hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4795).

For anyone who stumbles across this question. One workaround is to use "Exists":

```
SELECT e FROM AogReference e WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT p FROM Pack p WHERE p.aogReference = e)
```